# Multi-level city high enough off the ground to have atmospheric controls

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a book that I read in the late 70s/early 80s. All I can remember is that it took place on a planet where the main city consisted of several levels and that they were so high off the ground that they had sophisticated atmospheric controls. I also think the protagonist was a female, maybe a thief? Sorry this is so vague on the details, but I can't stop thinking about this novel.

Comment: Sounds like [*The Jetsons.*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0055683/)

Comment: Is it one city, or a mountain with lots of them? I'm thinking of Lord Valentine's Castle by Robert Silverberg."Set in an immense world teeming with alien races and fantastic magical machinery, Valentine wakes up one morning with only a vague and troubled idea of who he is. His dreams suggest he is the ruler of Majipor - but no one will believe him."